# Trying to show multiple photos inserted in Laravel voyager?

Tags: laravel-5.6, voyager

I tried to retrieve in my front-end a multiple photos inserted from the admin panel Lararel Voyager , I tried this solution but it still showing an error . the code is below :

[image]

and I get this error :

[image]

If anyone can help I'd be grateful .'

Answer (score 3):

your code is wrong use bellow code for show images

```
@foreach(json_decode($sld->image, true) as $image)
    <img src="{{ Voyager::image($image) }}" />
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1):

**this is my controller**

```
public function show()
{
   $show = Product::query()
    return view('index_event.yourview')->with('shows',$show);
}
```

**yourview**

```
@if(isset($shows->img))
            <?php $images = json_decode($shows->img); ?>
            @if($images != null)
                @foreach($images as $image)
                        <img  src="{{ Voyager::image( $image ) }}"  >
                @endforeach
            @endif
@endif
```

*let test*